# Outer Join based on DateTime field in LINQ, missing months

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My question is how to perform a left outer join, but to include missing values based on a datetime field, in linqToEF/SQL. I'm trying to cut down a huge problem to ask my specific question.

I have 3 tables. Picture them below.

- timelogs | Id, StartDateTime, AccountNumber, ContractNumber
- contracts | Id, ContractNumber, AccountNumber, Value, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
- accounts | Id, AccountNumber, AccountName, Email, FirstName, LastName

I'm performing a group by in linq like this:

```
group new {contracts, timelogs} by new { accounts.AccountNumber, accounts.AccountName, Year = timelogs.StartDateTime.Year, Month = timelogs.StartDateTime.Month } into g
```

The timelogs table only includes timelogs that have been submitted for a month with a particular account. If no timelogs have been submitted, it won't output any entry, as I would expect.

See this example:

Account "Blah" doesn't have any timelogs submitted for month 5. Hence, missing entry for for Blah in the sample output below.

```
AccountName | Account Number | Month | Year
Bling           654321          5      2013
Bling           654321          6      2013
Blah            123456          6      2013
Bling           654321          7      2013
Blah            123456          7      2013
Bling           654321          8      2013
Blah            123456          8      2013
```

I've tried to do this, but alas, this doesn't work due to the array being local.

```
join months in new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 } on timelogs.StartDateTime.Month equals months
join years in new int[] { 2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016 } on timelogs.StartDateTime.Year equals months
```

How do I perform a join in linq to SQL / entity framework, based missing months/years from a DateTime field? I want to include Blah, for month 5, even if it does not have any timelogs.

Comment: Do you have to get the whole outer join in EF/SQL? Could you perhaps use just the grouping in EF, and then fill in the gaps locally?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon, very appreciated. I was toying with that idea. The only issue I see with doing that, is that contract information can vary between months - depending on when the contract starts and ends. I'll try your suggestion next

Answer (score 0):

you cant join on local lists, but you can use Contains on local lists ( they get passed as parameters, so be wary of the number of items in your lists...)

you could try doing

```
group new {contracts, timelogs} by new { accounts.AccountNumber, accounts.AccountName, Year = timelogs.StartDateTime.Year, Month = timelogs.StartDateTime.Month } into g
where new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 }.Contains(g.Month)
&& new int[] { 2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016 }.Contains(g.Year)
```

i would still feel kind of icky doing it this way

Comment: This would work for 'where', but I'm trying to do a join based on the information. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you do this 'where', it will always succeed because the months output from the group will always be in the lists that we've created locally

Comment: you're right, i somehow forgot between reading the question and seeing the joins that it was supposed to be an outer join. this wouldn't work...